# Issues if Ubuntu and Windows 7 is installed in dualboot

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I wondered if there are any known issues when Ubuntu and WIndows 7 are installed in Dualboot. I figured out that Ubuntu sometimes runs a bit slow.

Comment: There is no way that I can imagine that would make ether run slow. If the other OS has not booted, and therefore is not running, then how can it make the running OS slower?

Comment: Is Dualboot a product? or do you mean dualboot?

Comment: excuse me, i meant dualboot... i am confused because i thought i might have installed the Ubuntu system mixed with the windows. So there should be no problem even if i use ubuntu and for example use programs with wine from windows directory and for example save data in same directory?